# Angular-Unit testing: ng test command not working

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am working on an angular project. I want to add karma & jasmine testing to my project. I did all the necessary setups and created a spec.ts file with testcases.

When I put `npm test` command I got the below output:

```
PS C:\Users\Vinay\retailer-webapp> npm test

> retialer-webapp@1.0.0 test C:\Users\Vinay\retailer-webapp
> ng test

PS C:\Users\Vinay\retailer-webapp>
```

The test cases are not executed and karma is also not initialized.

PS: I don't know how to debug the command execution process.

Comment: npm install -g karma-cli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the 'karma' command, you will need to install the following:

npm install -g karma-cli

As specified by the [official documentation](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/intro/installation.html): you need a separate package to use karma within command line interface

Otherwise you would need to call karma from within the node_modules folder everytime

[image]